# Example of certain curve

Tags: differential-geometry

It's known that a smooth curve of speed one (i.e parametrized by arc length) in R^3 with non-zero curvature and zero torsion (everywhere) is contained in a plane. I need to prove (by giving an example) that if the curvature is zero even at  a single point, then the curve no longer has to be planar.

Comment: Hint: Construct a smooth plane curve that contains a line segment $AB$ which divides this curve to two separate parts, then rotate one part around $AB$ while fix the other part

Comment: This is not clear to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: For example, consider the bump function $\Phi(x)$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), consider the graph of $f(x):=\Phi(x-1)+\Phi(x+1)$, then the derivative of $f(x)$ of any order at $0$ vanishes, then you rotate the $x>0$ part of the graph of $f(x)$ around the $x$-axis will produce an example.

Comment: I revisited this example, and maybe it wasn't clear from the phrasing of the question, but the curve needs to have unit speed, so derivative of 0 at 0 is not good. Any idea how I can get around that?

Comment: If you treat the graph $(x,f(x))$ as a curve parametrised by $x$, then its derivative is $(1,f'(x))$ which is nonzero at any time, so you can find a new parameter to make the curve to be speed one.

Comment: $f$ has derivative of any order $0$ at $0$ is needed to make the curvature at $0$ vanish.

Answer (score 0):

The graph $y=x^3$ is a $C^2$-smooth planar curve, hence of zero torsion. Its curvature vanishes only at the inflection point $x=0$. This is not an example you want.

The graph $y=|x|^3$ is also a $C^2$-smooth planar curve, hence of zero torsion. Its curvature vanishes only at the inflection point $x=0$. This is not an example, either.

Comparing the two curves above, you should realize that the point $(0,0)$ is kind of a rotary joint, which allows one half of the curve to be rotated about the $x$-axis. Rotate it by an angle $\ne 0,\pi$. *This* is an example.

Comment: But your curve is no longer smooth after rotation.